# Android Studio on a Mac: log messages not shown

Tags: android, macos

Android Studio on my OS X Yosemite very often stops displaying log messages written by my app under development.

If I go to the ADB logs tab I see a plenty of different error messages:

1) Broken pipe:

```
ddmlib: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

2) null

```
ddms: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.read(Client.java:731)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:311)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

3) Closed connections

```
DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '5022': closed
```

4) Unauthorized device

```
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device HT4C9JT00135: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

5) EOF

```
DeviceMonitor: Adb connection Error:EOF
```

It would be funny if this wasn't  the development environment for Android.

I was able to solve only error number 4 (I had to forget associated devices and authorize again).

I tried combos of answers found here on SO (for example adb kill/start-server), enabling the ADB integration (which was disabled), ....

Besides planning a trip to Lourdes, what else can I check to see why Android Studio refuses to log my messages? It used to work till some days ago: problems started after the upgrade to 1.1.

---

**Update**

I uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio.

The first time I ran my app adb worked fine: I could see the log messages. From the second run, adb started refusing connections again (problem 3).

Is there anyone who was able to solve this incredible mess?

---

**2nd Update**
When there are no log messages, if I unplug and plug again the USB cable, the messages magically appears.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable?

Comment: I have the same issue, it seems to be an issue in Android Studio itself (the same happens with Emulator) so @CommonsWare it's not a USB issue

Comment: Yes, it's not a USB issue: I have tested a couple of different cables I have. I wonder how they think we can develop software with this IDE: this problem (plus other idiosyncrasies) made me lose almost two days of work - and now it's not yet working.

Comment: Furthermore, this issue showed up as soon as I upgraded to version 1.1